Struggling to Configure Nginx Reverse Proxy for HTTPS (Port 443)
I've been struggling with this issue for almost two weeks now and need some help. I'm hosting a simple app on my server to test it online. To set it up properly, I decided to use Nginx as a reverse proxy for my Node.js application.
The Goal
I want to be able to connect to my app using HTTPS (port 443) without having to specify any port in the URL. Currently, I can connect to the server on different ports (e.g., 8080 or 443), but I always need to include the port number explicitly. I would like to make this seamless and work as expected for HTTPS.
Here’s everything I’ve tried so far:

Network Configuration:

I’ve opened the necessary ports on my router:
Public 80 -> Private 80
Public 443 -> Private 443
Public 8080 -> Private 8080




Node.js Express Server:

My Express app is set up to listen on port 8080. Here’s my server/index.js file:
const express = require('express');
const routes = require('./routes');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

const httpPort = 8080;

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api', routes);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client", "dist")));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client", "dist", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(httpPort, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${httpPort}`);
});




Nginx Configuration:

My Nginx is configured to:

Redirect HTTP traffic (port 80) to HTTPS (port 443).
Proxy traffic from port 443 to my Node.js app on port 8080.


Here’s my Nginx configuration:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name MY_SERVER_NAME;

    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name MY_SERVER_NAME;

    ssl_certificate /home/<user>/certificates/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/<user>/certificates/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}




Firewall Rules (UFW):

All necessary ports (80, 443, 8080) are open:
To      Action    From
443/tcp ALLOW     Anywhere
80/tcp  ALLOW     Anywhere
8080/tcp ALLOW    Anywhere




Checking Sockets:

When I start my Node.js server and check active sockets using ss -tuln, I can see:
tcp   LISTEN   0   511    0.0.0.0:443    0.0.0.0:*
tcp   LISTEN   0   511       *:8080       *:*






The Problem
Despite all this, I cannot connect to my app seamlessly on HTTPS (port 443). I still need to manually specify the port in the URL for the connection to work.
When I visit https://MY_SERVER_NAME, the page takes a while to load and then I get the error: ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED. If I try to ping or curl the server, no packets are received.
Then :
https://MY_SERVER_NAME:443 => Not Working
https://MY_SERVER_NAME:80 => Not Working => redirect to my https://MY_SERVER_NAME:443
http://MY_SERVER_NAME:8080 => Working
It seems like the server isn't responding at all. Could it be related to the port or something else? Let me know if I should provide more details!
UPDATE
I made some changes, like deleting the default file in my
/etc/nginx/sites-available, changed my node port several time and
moving the port on my network like :
Public 80 -> Private {new node port}
Public 445 -> Private {new node port}

So now :
https://MY_SERVER_NAME:443 => Not Working
https://MY_SERVER_NAME:80 => Not Working => redirect to my https://MY_SERVER_NAME:443
http://MY_SERVER_NAME:{new Node Port} => Not Working
https://{MyPublicIP} => Not working
https://{MyPublicIP}:{new Node Port} => Working
localhost => Working
https://{IPV4} => Working
Question :
I’m honestly unsure whether it’s better or worse at this point. I think I first need to understand how to properly set up my network as a reverse proxy. Should the private network be configured to point to my Node.js port, or should both the public and private configurations be the same?

Problem Solved!
The issue was with my network. Technically, my site was accessible from the start, but I encountered a 'loopback' problem caused by my network. The problem was that my network didn't allow external connections to loop back to itself. From what I understand, this can usually be fixed via NAT configuration on your internal network (192.168.x.x). However, in my case, my network didn't even have that option.
So, I had to resolve it manually by editing the following file:
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host
Here's what I added to the file:
192.168.x.x    {your DNS}

Where 192.168.x.x is the IPv4 address of the computer running the program (in my case, it was 192.168.0.10), and {your DNS} is the DNS name of your website.
So, in my case, it looked like this:
192.168.0.10    mywebsite.local

If this can help someone else, great! And if you have any questions, feel free to ask — I'm happy to help.
How to know if you're facing the same problem:
Try accessing your website using a different internet connection, like the mobile data on your phone. If it works on another network but not on your own, there’s a high chance you’re dealing with the same loopback issue.

You should post your solution as answer below and accept it, not make it part of the question.
